# Ng serve does nothing. Doesnt work. No messages or errors

Tags: angular-cli

There is no mesages or errors. I tried npm install, ng update , npm update. Whats wrong ?

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.6
Node: 16.18.0
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.0.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1100.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1100.2
@angular-devkit/core            11.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.6
@angular/cli                    14.2.6
@schematics/angular             14.2.6
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

If it does nothing that means installation is corrupt or you have differences between local and global Angular.

Please do following:

```
1. npm uninstall -g angular-cli
2. npm cache clean
3. npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

Or if you don't need global installation just remove -g from npm uninstall/install.

Comment: Didn't workout :(

Comment: Can you try with npm start? If that dont work pls share the angular.json file configuration