# Ng serve doesn't work, no errors or messages to show what's the issue

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After a recent update to MacOS Sonoma, `ng serve` stopped working. I can run `ng version`, and it will show the version, but when I try `ng serve` in my project it does nothing. The cursor in the terminal just keeps blinking like it's trying to process the command.

In accordance with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122125/ng-serve-does-nothing-doesnt-work-no-messages-or-errors) Q + A on stackoverflow, I uninstalled and reinstalled the Angular CLI globally. Still no luck. I also tried using `npm start`, which also didn't work.

Here is the angular.json file for my project if that helps clarify things any.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular.io-example": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.css"],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular.io-example:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "angular.io-example:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular.io-example:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.css"],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "angular.io-example:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "angular.io-example:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, you might want to consider removing node_modules + .angular folders, reinstall dependencies et retry again. tell me if you got anything new.

Comment: @millenion, this worked! Thank you so much! Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comment, removing all cache worked:

```
rm -rf node_modules .angular
```

Reinstall dependencies and that's it.